# Error in JUnit with static final List

Tags: java, junit

I've written a JUnit where it is calling a Constant class, here we are trying to access a **static final List**

```
public static final List<String> SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST = new ArrayList<String>();

static{ SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST.add(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_DISPLAY); 
    SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST.add(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_SUB); 
    SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST.add(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_SUB_GROUP); 
    SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST.add(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_SUB_GROUP_ID); 
    SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST.add(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID); 
    SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST.add(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_GROUP_ID); }
```

Now, while accessing this List via JUnit thread I'm gettting this error.

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:222)
        at com.mns.commerce.searchnav.constants.MSEndecaConstants.<clinit>(MSEndecaConstants.java:169)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
        at com.mns.commerce.searchnav.utils.MSSearchResposeBOTransformer.getRefinementsDetails(MSSearchResposeBOTransformer.java:460)
        at com.mns.commerce.searchnav.utils.MSSearchResposeBOTransformer.buildFacets(MSSearchResposeBOTransformer.java:362)
        at com.mns.commerce.searchnav.utils.MSSearchResposeBOTransformer.populateResults(MSSearchResposeBOTransformer.java:106)
        at com.mns.commerce.searchnavunit.test.MSSearchResposeBOTransformerTest.testPopulateResults(MSSearchResposeBOTransformerTest.java:97)
```

Whereas, if an static `Enum` is defined instead of a `static final list` then it is working fine. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What happens if you remove the final modifier from the list declaration?

Comment: Try putting a try / catch (Throwable t) block around the code within the static initializer, and see if it is actually throwing an exception of some description. This will give you a better clue.

Answer (score 0):

This code is also running and I don't have any error with this code. My JDK version is 1.6.

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

```
public class test {

private static final String PRODUCT_CATEGORY_DISPLAY = "a";
private static final String PRODUCT_CATEGORY_SUB = "b";
private static final String PRODUCT_CATEGORY_SUB_GROUP = "c";
private static final String PRODUCT_CATEGORY_SUB_GROUP_ID = "d";
private static final String PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID = "e";
private static final String PRODUCT_CATEGORY_GROUP_ID = "f";
public static final List<String> SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST = new ArrayList<String>();

static{          
    SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST.add(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_DISPLAY);
    SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST.add(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_SUB);
    SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST.add(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_SUB_GROUP);
    SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST.add(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_SUB_GROUP_ID);
    SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST.add(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID);
    SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST.add(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_GROUP_ID);
}      /**      * @param args      */     
public static void main(String[] args) {   
    System.out.println(SKIPPED_DIMENSION_LIST); 
} 

}
```